# How to install OSX El Capitan downloaded from ftp server?

Tags: macos

I downloaded OSX El Capitan in one Mac, then I copied installation files (.app) to shared ftp folder. In another Macs It doesn't start. Is it for security? Can I do that? Can I copy installation files to USB?

Comment: How come OSX El Capitan is more than 1 file? Try copying the main installer rather than the files inside the installer.

Comment: I copied all files. I think that some issue happens through FTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you download the installer from the AppStore, it is saved as `Install OS X El Capitan.app` in the Applications folder. Behind the scene `.app` files are really just folders which are treated as a single file by the OS. My guess is that you either have an incomplete file or something has gone wrong when you copied the file to the ftp server.

If you compress the `.app` (control+click > `Compress "Install OS X El Capitan"`) and then copy the resulting archive to the ftp folder your other macs will be able to download the archive, uncompress it and run the app.
Or you can just copy `Install OS X El Capitan.app` to a USB drive or even [create a bootable USB drive](http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/11/make-bootable-os-x-el-capitan-beta-install-usb-drive/) which you can then use as a rescue installation drive.

Comment: Right now, I've not proved what You say, but I guess you have reason.
Few months ago, I've copied OS X Yosemite installation files in a USB (exFat), and It worked, but I guessed that It would work through FTP. I will prove compressing the folder.